# SQL - Add missing rows by duplicating existing rows while selecting from table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table TABLE1 as in screen shot.

[image]

Column SALES_DATE max value is 20230630 and if we run report as of today 20231005 then it should add rows for all missing months till last day of the month as of todays date = 20231031 for example . All other column values can be the same .

[image]

The final table after select should be like this and I have highlighted the new rows

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL Select statement ?

Am getting references like this in google but not sure where to start

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 'value2' AND column3 = 'value3'
);